# Python WebSocket connection refused in Docker

Tags: python, docker, http, websocket

I have a python socketio application that works just fine when run locally. However, when I move it into Docker, external clients are unable to connect and throw this error:

```py
socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

The WebSocket server is really basic and publishes to `0.0.0.0:8080`. My client apps listen to `localhost:8080`. In my Docker container, I've exposed port 8080. I'm guessing that I'm setting up my container incorrectly.:

Dockerfile:

```bash
FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /path/to/project

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    working_dir: /path/to/project
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /path/to/project
```

I start up my container with `docker-compose up` and I'm using Docker Desktop (if that helps). I use this environment for development so I start my server with `python my_server.py`. The server starts successfully. What else am I missing?

I've tried the following based on what others have said about this problem online

- Explicitly setting `0.0.0.0` to be the host
- Using `EXPOSE 8080` in my Dockerfile
- Set the network mode to `host`

Comment: Can you please provide the `docker-compose.yaml` and `Dockerfile`?

Comment: I've updated my post to contain them!

Comment: Thank you. You have not specified any command to run in your container. Are you sure your server is actually running on port 8080? You typically do this with `CMD` in your `Dockerfile` or specify `cmd` in your `docker-compose.yaml`.

Comment: Since I use the container for development, I manually start the server with `python my_server.py`

Comment: You can perhaps try to add `CMD ["python", "my_server.py"]` to your Dockerfile and try running docker-compose again. If that works, we can at least verify that your container setup is functional (which I have reason to believe it is).

Comment: That's also the recommended way to develop with `docker`. Running commands inside running containers for dev work is not the right way. You essentially run `docker compose` every time you test a new change. That's how it goes.

Comment: What on earth... why does this work? Well, thank you for your help. Also, does this have to be done through the docker file, or is there a way to run commands and pass in CLI arguments to this python script via the compose file? Sorry, I'm still learning docker.

Comment: It's totally possible with compose file as well! I'll update my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container connectivity appears to be fine.

You have not specified any command to run in your container. In order to ensure your server is actually running on port 8080, you can add a `CMD` instruction in your Dockerfile or specify cmd in your `docker-compose.yaml`. This can be done with:

```
CMD ["python", "my_server.py"]
```

Or with `docker-compose.yaml` file as:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    working_dir: /path/to/project
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: python my_server.py #<== this overrides the Dockerfile CMD instruction
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /path/to/project
```

You can learn more about `command` in `docker-compose.yaml` [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command).

That's also the recommended way to develop with docker. Running commands inside running containers for dev work is not the right way. You essentially run docker compose every time you test a new change. That avoids a lot of problems like these where connectivity doesn't work.

Comment: Does this have to be done through the docker file, or is there a way to run commands and pass in CLI arguments to this python script via the compose file? Sorry, I'm still learning docker.